# passing function as a props

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm not able to understand how to call a function from parent component to a child component in React. It just calls the functions from TestEvent and renders the old data on form. Control not going to ManageComment's component functions.

```html
class TestEvent extends Component{
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state={
    editing:false,
    comment:this.props.comment   
  };
  this.commentRef=React.createRef(); // to create a ref to the DOM element
}

  edit(){
    this.setState({editing:true}) ;   
  }
  save(){   
    this.setState({editing:false});
    this.props.updatecomment.bind(this.commentRef.current.value,this.props.index);
  }
  remove(){   
    this.props.deletecomment.bind(this.props.index);
  }

renderNormal(){
 return(    
      <div className="commentContainer">
        <div className="commentText">{this.state.comment}</div>
        <div className="commentBtn">
        <button className="b1" onClick={this.edit.bind(this)} >Edit</button>
        <button className="b2" onClick={this.remove.bind(this) } >Remove</button>  
       </div>
      </div>
    );}
renderForm(){
  return(   
    <div className="commentContainer">
    <textarea ref={this.commentRef} defaultValue={this.state.comment}></textarea>         
      <div className="commentBtn">
      <button className="b3" onClick={this.save.bind(this)} >Save</button>        
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
  render(){ 
   if(this.state.editing){
   return this.renderForm();
   }else{
   return this.renderNormal();
   }
  }
}

// Need to manage comments from separate component here
class ManageComment extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state= {
      comments:[
                'First comment',
                'Second Comment',
                'Third comment'
              ]}              
  }
  // add functions to remove,edit comments from child
  // passing functions as a props
  updateComment(newComment,i){
    var arr=this.state.comments;
    arr[i]=newComment;
    this.setState({comments:arr});
  }
  deleteComment(i){
    var arr=this.state.comments;
    arr.splice(i,1);
    this.setState({comments:arr});    
  }
    render(){
      return(
            <div className="manageComment">
            {
              this.state.comments.map(function(text,i){
                return (
                  <TestEvent
                   key={i}              
                   index={i}
                   comment={text}
                   updatecomment={this.updateComment.bind(text,i)} 
                   deletecomment={this.deleteComment.bind(i)}> </TestEvent>);
              },this)            
            }
            </div>
      );
    
  }
}
```

.
I've created a form to enter a comment in textarea,and giving options to edit/save/remove a comment.

Details of my code :

1. I've created 'TestEvent' component,wherein I've 3 options,Save,Remove and Edit to operate on Comment-Text.
2. Then I've 'ManageComment' component, where I'm rendering 'TestEvent' with some props as well as I'm passing functions with props called updatecomment and deletecomment.
3. Finally,I'm rendering 'ManageComment' component.
4. so basically here I've parent and child component and I'm trying to invoke function of 'ManageComment' component from 'TestEvent'.

Comment: In summary, is it correct that you want to pass a function to a child component and then use it from within?

Comment: Yes... @ionizer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you don't call the function but just bind() something to your functions. For example in your function you do following:

```
save = () => {   
    this.setState({editing:false});
    this.props.updatecomment.bind(this.commentRef.current.value,this.props.index);
  }
```

The problem is that `this.props.updatecomment.bind(this.commentRef.current.value,this.props.index);` does not execute your function but just binds the context. I would suggest you have another look at [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). What you want to do is to call your function instead of binding something to it e.g. `this.props.updatecomment(this.commentRef.current.value,this.props.index);`.

Why exactly do you need a commentRef? You could just access the value of your textarea through the event which gets called when you save it. If you call the event you can find the data in `event.target`. Check in it where the value for your text area is.

```
  save = (event) {
    this.setState({editing:false});
    const commentValue = event.target
    this.props.updatecomment(commentValue, this.props.index)
  }
```

Also a suggestion from my side to make your code more readable I would suggest you use arrow functions if you want to bind the context of your component

```js
  class ManageComment extends Component{
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state= {
        comments:[
                  'First comment',
                  'Second Comment',
                  'Third comment'
                ]}              
    }
    // add functions to remove,edit comments from child
    // passing functions as a props
    updateComment = (newComment,i) =>{
      var arr=this.state.comments;
      arr[i]=newComment;
      this.setState({comments:arr});
    }
    deleteComment = (i) => {
      var arr=this.state.comments;
      arr.splice(i,1);
      this.setState({comments:arr});    
    }
      render(){
        return(
              <div className="manageComment">
              {
                this.state.comments.map(function(text,i){
                  return (
                    <TestEvent
                     key={i}              
                     index={i}
                     comment={text}
                     updatecomment={this.updateComment} 
                     deletecomment={this.deleteComment}> </TestEvent>);
                },this)            
              }
              </div>
        );
      
    }
  }
```

Another suggestion is that you use `let` and `const` instead of `var`. There is a lot of literature out there on why it makes sense to no longer use var -> [literature](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-es6-var-let-or-const-ba58b8dcde75). As a rule of thumb you can just always use `const` and when the compiler complains switch to `let`;

Comment: Hey Thank you so much for your amazing explanation,I tried your suggested solution but now facing new error i.e "  Cannot read property 'comments' of undefined " at line " var arr=this.state.comments; " in deleteComment function. Pls help :)

Comment: I would suggest to inspect what this.state has? You probably made a wrong binding of context. Just make a ```console.log(this)``` and figure out what this refers to. Then you can backtrack where the problem with your this is and change the binding at that point.

Comment: Also maybe I wasn't clear about ```event.target```. You need to check the ```event.target```. It will have a couple of properties and one of them is the value of your comment. It is probably ```event.target.value``` but I would have to check again which one exactly holds the value of your comment.

Comment: Thanks..It worked ! I've other issue now i.e  deleteComment function is working fine and deleting only that comment whose index has been passed but after rendering the form it shows that last comment has deleted,so it deletes last comment only no matter what index has been passed .. How to solve this problem?

Comment: I can't really answer that without seeing more code. Maybe you should create a second question.

Answer (score 0):

You have already passed `updateComment()` and `deleteComment()` as props named `updatecomment` and `deletecomment` for `TestEvent` component. But, those functions should be bound like so:

```
updatecomment={this.updateComment.bind(this)} 
deletecomment={this.deleteComment.bind(this)}
```

You don't need to bind those functions again. It's only a matter of using it like so:

```
class TestEvent extends Component {
  ....
  save() {
    this.setState({editing:false})
    this.props.updatecomment(this.commentRef.current.value,this.props.index))
  }

  remove() {
    this.props.deletecomment(this.props.index)
  }
  ....
}
```

Comment: Yes I tried that solution but now facing new error i.e " Cannot read property 'comments' of undefined " at line " var arr=this.state.comments; " in deleteComment function. Pls help :)

Comment: Reset your React app and try `console.log(this.state)` inside `updateComment()` and `deleteComment()` before anything else. Let me know what it outputs. It seems like how you change the `comments` state array made it `undefined`, so I recommend rewriting how you deal with it.

Comment: Also, you might need to check for your array boundaries when using those functions so you don't encounter such errors.